# Query with Join condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, join

I have to write a query to make a relevant join on table1 and table2 by checking both values REFID and ORGID, to get the OUTPUT TABLE as shown below.

```
Table1:

REFID      ORGID    Artikel_ID   ORGID_ARTIKEL  Price
1001       1234     M123             1314         2,2
1001       1235     M124             1314         15,2
1001       1234     M125             1322         20,5

Table2:

REFID      ORGID    MATNR    Turnover   Reduced_Turunover
1001       1234     1886     8000,6         2500,0
1001       1235     1886     9000,6         6500,0

Ouput Table:

REFID      ORGID    Artikel_ID   ORGID_ARTIKEL  Price      MATNR    Turnover   Reduced_Turunover
1001       1234     M123             1314         2,2      1886      8000,6     2500,0
1001       1235     M124             1314         15,2     1886      9000,6     6500,0
1001       1234     M125             1322         20,5      1886     8000,6     2500,0
```

I tried the following:

```
select T0."REFID"
     , T0."ORGID_WE"
     , T0."ARTIKEL_ID"
     , T0."ORGID_ARTIKEL"
     , sum(T0."Price")as Price
     , T1."MATNR"
     , T1."ORGID"
     , T1."VNTHW"
     , T1."Turnover"
     , T1."reduced_turnover"
  from TABLE1 T0 
 Inner Join 
       TABLE2 T1 
    on T0."REFID"=T1."REFID"
     , T0."ORGID"=T1."ORGID"
```

Firstly, I would like to ask if I could use two conditions as I have done above. If not can you help me in manipulating the following.

Thanks

Comment: Could anyone give me a reason why this is been downvoted?

Comment: Are you using ',' as a decimal separator?

Comment: It is probably because people expect you to show what you have tried and why it did not work, instead of just letting us start from a blank page.

Comment: you are asking for basic mysql usage, and u didnt even try to solve it, please take a read of [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). and i didnt vote down. just explaning the reason.

Comment: Thanks. That was my fault. I tried this for few hours and I took effort to post here only for the reason that I couldnt find a solution. Maybe I will update my question

Comment: you shuld do it. its on the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic question. You want to join two tables:

```
select * from table1 join table2 using (refid, orgid);
```

Comment: I just updated my question. Kindly look into it. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Yes, you can use ON instead of USING. Only, don't separate your conditions with AND, not with a comma then: ... on T0."REFID"=T1."REFID" and T0."ORGID"=T1."ORGID"

Comment: Next problem: when aggregating things (COUNT, SUM, etc.) you must declare the group you are aggregating for.

Comment: ´you must declare the group´ what does that actually mean. COuld you please brief a little bit? Thanks

Comment: Use GROUP BY. All fields you select must either be in the group by list or be aggregated (e.g. select a, b, min(c), sum(d) from t where ... group by a, b;)

Comment: Greta thank you so much. That was very useful. Have work onmm my basics. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiple conditions, but you have to put them together with `and`, not `,`.
also `sum()` can only be used when grouping.

```
select T0."REFID"
     , T0."ORGID"
     , T0."Artikel_ID"
     , T0."ORGID_ARTIKEL"
     , T0."Price"
     , T1."MATNR"
     , T1."Turnover"
     , T1."reduced_turnover"
  from TABLE1 T0 
 Inner Join 
       TABLE2 T1 
    on T0."REFID"=T1."REFID"
   and T0."ORGID"=T1."ORGID"
```